long time web scrapping using beautifulsoup in python
I want to scrape the title and date of news articles from the OilPrice website using this code:
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
import os
title_list = []
date_list = []
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Foued Azuz 14\mypythonfiles')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for page in range (104,110):
    url = f"https://oilprice.com/Energy/Crude-Oil/Page-{page}.html"
    driver.get(url)
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title= soup.find_all('div',class_='categoryArticle__content')
    for i in title:
            d = i.find('h2', class_='categoryArticle__title').text
            h = i.find('p', class_='categoryArticle__meta')
            date_str = h.get_text()
            date = date_str.split(' at ')[0]
            if 'oil' in d.lower():
                title_list.append(d)
                date_list.append(date)

data = {'date': date_list, 'Title': title_list}
scrapdataoil = pd.DataFrame(data)
scrapdataoil.to_csv('scrapdataoil104110.csv', index=False)
 

The code works fine; however, my issue is that it takes a long time to loop from one page to another. Is there any way to speed up the execution since I need to loop through many pages?
I want to extract the date and title from news articles, but the algorithm is time-consuming.

Why do you load the driver and imports several times?

If you're using selenium you don't need to use BeautifulSoup

use the threading or asyncio modules to make multiple parallel I/O requests. This would be, by far, the biggest gain.

works with requests, without selenium. this is probably one of your bottlenecks. took 5s to run your script

You don't need BeautifulSoup if you're using selenium
Here's a robust solution for acquiring the data you're interested in. Uses multithreading for improved performance
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

DWAIT = 5
OUTPUT_FILE = "foo.csv"
URL = "https://oilprice.com/Energy/Crude-Oil/Page-{}.html"

def get_text(element):
    if element:
        if t := element.get_attribute("textContent"):
            return t.strip()
    return ""

def get_element(driver, selector):
    return driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)

def main(page):
    _date = []
    _title = []
    with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
        driver.get(URL.format(page))
        articles = WebDriverWait(driver, DWAIT).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.categoryArticle")))
        for article in articles:
            title = get_text(get_element(article, "h2.categoryArticle__title"))
            if title and "oil" in title.lower():
                meta = get_text(get_element(article, "p.categoryArticle__meta"))
                if meta:
                    _title.append(title)
                    _date.append(" ".join(meta.split()[:3]))
    return _title, _date
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    data = {
            "Date": [],
            "Title": []
        }
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        for _title, _date in exe.map(main, range(104, 110)):
            data["Title"].extend(_title)
            data["Date"].extend(_date)
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(OUTPUT_FILE, index=False)
    end = time.time()
    print(f"Duration={end-start:.2f}s")

Output:
3.70s

Update:
The website being scraped does not appear to depend on JavaScript to the extent that selenium might be required.
Using multithreading and a combination of requests and BeautifulSoup we can improve performance significantly as follows:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

OUTPUT_FILE = "foo.csv"
URL = "https://oilprice.com/Energy/Crude-Oil/Page-{}.html"

def main(session, page):
    titles = []
    dates = []
    with session.get(URL.format(page)) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BS(response.text, "lxml")
        for article in soup.select("div.categoryArticle"):
            if title := article.select_one("h2.categoryArticle__title"):
                if (title := title.text) and "oil" in title.lower():
                    if meta := article.select_one("p.categoryArticle__meta"):
                        titles.append(title.strip())
                        dates.append(" ".join(meta.text.strip().split()[:3]))
    return titles, dates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    data = {
            "Date": [],
            "Title": []
        }
    with requests.Session() as session:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
            for _title, _date in exe.map(partial(main, session), range(104, 110)):
                data["Title"].extend(_title)
                data["Date"].extend(_date)
        pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(OUTPUT_FILE, index=False)
        end = time.time()
        print(f"Duration={end-start:.2f}s")

Output:
0.90s


and that's even faster without selenium (on my machine: 5.4s without threads vs 1.7s with threads). that's quite simple to implement, i didn't know. thanks

@diggusbickus Sure. If there's no JavaScript dependency (in terms of how the pages are rendered) then requests in conjunction with BeautifulSoup will almost certainly be faster. There's a significant overhead in creating the selenium (Chrome in this case) driver
